# ReactJS html5 video - how do you catch video's controls on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video

I need to do various actions depending if the user clicked on the `play` / `pause` controls or if he wants to select a specific moment of the video.

So far I've done that:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        videoSrc: "static/dt1.mp4",
    }
    this.testClick = this.testClick.bind(this);
}
testClick(evt) {
  console.log("hello");
}

render() {
  return (
    <video ref={(video1) => { this.video1 = video1; }} onClick={this.testClick} width="100%" height="350"controls>
      <source src={this.state.videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
}
```

So, here if I click on the video itself I've the hello printing. But if I click on the controls, nothing happen...

Maybe I'm searching it wrong but I couldn't find anything on google so far.

How can I know if the user clicked on play / pause or select a time frame of the video? Do I need absolutely a library like:
http://docs.videojs.com/index.html ?

Ps: I don't want to use any jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using react you can use any of the [media events](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#media-events):

> onAbort onCanPlay onCanPlayThrough onDurationChange onEmptied onEncrypted 
>   onEnded onError onLoadedData onLoadedMetadata onLoadStart onPause onPlay 
>   onPlaying onProgress onRateChange onSeeked onSeeking onStalled onSuspend 
>   onTimeUpdate onVolumeChange onWaiting

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        videoSrc: "static/dt1.mp4",
    }
    this.testClick = this.testClick.bind(this);
    this.onPlay = this.onPlay.bind(this);
}

testClick (evt) { 
  console.log("hello");
}

onPlay (evt) {
    console.log("video start play");
}

render() {
  return (
    <video ref={(video1) => { this.video1 = video1; }} onClick={this.testClick} width="100%" height="350" onPlay={this.onPlay} controls>
      <source src={this.state.videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply wrap `video` within a `div` on catch `onClick` on wrap.

```html
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        videoSrc: "static/dt1.mp4",
    }
    this.testClick = this.testClick.bind(this);
}
testClick(evt) {
  console.log("hello");
}

render() {
  return (
    <div onClick={this.testClick}>
      <video ref={(video1) => { this.video1 = video1; }} width="100%" height="350"controls>
        <source src={this.state.videoUrl} type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```