# Reactjs - onClick works when video is clicked but not when the video controller is clicked?

Tags: html, reactjs, video

I am currently building a site in react and I have a html video element with an onClick.

```
<video id="video" className="videos" controls onClick={playVideo.bind(this, 'play', 'video')}>
    <source src="something.mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

The onClick works if you press the actual video itself but doesn't work when you click on the video controller. Is there away to get the onClick firing when you click the video controller?

Comment: Why do you need an onClick in `<video />` the video will have controls play/pause etc. The video will still be able to run.

Comment: I need an onClick because I need to pause a previous video when another video is played!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881073/reactjs-html5-video-how-do-you-catch-videos-controls-on-click Have you seen this?

Comment: I have not but that’s is perfect thank you!